# Assembling file errors

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, x86-16, tasm

What should I change that the error at `tasm /zi file name` would disappear?

ERROR TYPE

> ex1.ASM(16) Operand types do not much

The expression `300-[5*(d-2*a)-1]`, data types: a -byte, d -word

The code :

```
   ASSUME cs:text_,ds:data_
data_ SEGMENT
a db 2
d dd 4
res dd ?
data_ ENDS

text_ SEGMENT
start:
mov bl,2;
mov al,a;
imul bl;ax=2*a
mov bx,d; bx=d
sub bx,ax;bx=d-2*a
mov ax,5;
imul bx; dxax=5*(d-2a)
sub ax,1;
sbb dx,0; dxax= 5*(d-2a)-1
mov bx,300; 
mov cx,0;cxbx =300
;cxbx
;dxax
sub bx,ax; 
sbb cx,dx;300-[5*(d-2*a)-1]
mov word ptr res+0,bx; 
mov word ptr res+2,cx;
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
text_ ENDS

END start
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare `d` with `dd`, which makes it a dword (4 bytes). Later, you have `mov bx,d` which tries to load a 4 byte value into a 2 byte register.

You should declare `d` with `dw`:

```
d dw 4
```